# Trying to get the message from server but receive call gets blocked

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

**// This is send message from where I am sending message to server, Its working fine**

public void sendMessage(com.google.protobuf.Message sendmessage) {

```
try {
  createJmsTemplate();
  createJmsTemplateReciever();
  JmsMessageCreator jmsMessageCreator = new JmsMessageCreator() {
    @Override
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
      BytesMessage msg = session.createBytesMessage();
      msg.writeBytes(sendmessage.toByteArray());
      return msg;
    }
  };

  MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
      Message msg = jmsMessageCreator.createMessage(session);
      msg.setJMSCorrelationID("2708");
      return msg;
    }
  };

  jmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
  System.out.println("Message sent... ");

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(0);
}
```

}

**//But when i am calling this method, at receive call it gets blocked...**

public void recieveMessage() {
    try {

```
  byteMessage = (BytesMessage) jmsTemplateReciever.receive();
  try {
    if (byteMessage != null) {
      byte[] byteArr = new byte[(int) byteMessage.getBodyLength()];
      for (int i = 0; i < (int) byteMessage.getBodyLength(); i++) {
        byteArr[i] = byteMessage.readByte();
        String s = new String(byteArr);
        System.out.println(s);
      }
      String s = new String(byteArr);
      System.out.println(s);

      byteMessage.acknowledge();
    }

  } catch (JMSException e) {

  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(0);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

As described in section 9.2.2 of JMS 1.1 Specification, the `receive()` call blocks indefinitely until a message arrives on the queue. Hence the call is getting blocked in your application.

One option for you is to specify a wait time, for example `receive(3000)` which waits for 3 seconds and comes out if no message arrives in 3 seconds. JMS implementer might be providing another form of `receive` method where the method returns immediately if there are no messages in the queue.

The other option is to use a message listener for receiving messages asynchronously as described JMS 1.1 Specifications section 9.3.1. Your application gets notified by the JMS provider whenever a message arrives in a queue.